# Separating a list in python into tuples

Tags: python, list, nested, tuples

I have a nested list where 2 lists are included in the main list. The 2nd list has no items
lets say 
`A = [[3,4,5,1,6,],[]]`

I want to separate the 1st list into tuples in a way that it gives the following output:
output >>  (3,4),(4,5),(5,1),(1,6)

Can you please help me with this??

Comment: Please show what you have tried based on your research around this requirement

Comment: How about a list comprehension `tups = [(lst[0][i], lst[0][i+1]) for i in range(len(lst[0])-1)]`

Comment: @Bazingaa - It works perfectly. Thanks a lot for your support and I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
result = [(A[0][i],A[0][i+1]) for i in range(len(A[0])-1)]
```

output:

```
[(3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 1), (1, 6)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..... This is exactly what i wanted :D

Comment: Welcome, if this answer helps you then you can accept the answer by pressing on the tick mark

Comment: I accepted it and the tick is in green colour now